# simple bootstrap modal for php datatable more info

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

i want to show some database information in my page by table with php and for more info users have to click to more information...

i have currently this codes:

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "simozar");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table dir='rtl' class='table table-bordered'>
             <tr>
                 <td>name</td>
                 <td>job</td>
                 <td>phone number</td>
             </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                 <td>$row[first_name] $row[last_name]</td>
                 <td>$row[job]</td>
                 <td>$row[phone_num]</td>
                 <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-
                  toggle='modal' data-target='#more_info'>show more info</button></td>
              </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "no information";
}

$connection->close();
?>


<div id="more_info" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

               echo "<table dir='rtl' class='table table-bordered'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>name</td>
                            <td>job</td>
                            <td>phone number</td>
                            <td>home address</td>
                            <td>postal code</td>
                            <td>home phone number</td>
                            <td>date</td>
                        </tr>";
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     echo "<tr>
                               <td>$row[first_name] $row[last_name]</td>
                               <td>$row[job]</td>
                               <td>$row[phone_num]</td>
                               <td>$row[home_address]</td>
                               <td>$row[postcode]</td>
                               <td>$row[home_phone_num]</td>
                               <td>$row[date]</td>
                           </tr>";
    }
               echo "</table>";
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i have a simple table on my page with a button(in this table i have some rows from table), i want to show all rows from this table in a modal by click on a button...

Comment: What did you get when you click on button? What is your problem? Please specify.

Comment: @ankit i got nothing.i want to know how to send selected row id(by clicking show more info button) to modal ...

Comment: You missed `<?php` opening and `?>` closeing in your `modal-body` block.

Comment: can u send full code here?thx man...

Comment: modal is treated as a different page. You cant simply query from current page then show it on modal directly. You can query again or use js for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` must be unique in case of call modal using js.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "simozar");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table dir='' class='table table-bordered'>
             <tr>
                 <td>name</td>
                 <td>job</td>
                 <td>phone number</td>
             </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                 <td>$row[first_name] $row[last_name]</td>
                 <td>$row[job]</td>
                 <td>$row[phone_num]</td>
                 <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#more_info".$row['phone_num']."'>show more info</button></td>
              </tr>";
                $modal.="<div id='more_info".$row['phone_num']."' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                <div class='modal-dialog'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                        <div class='modal-body'>
                            <table class='table table-bordered'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>name</td>
                                    <td>job</td>
                                    <td>phone number</td>
                                    <td>home address</td>
                                    <td>postal code</td>
                                    <td>home phone number</td>
                                    <td>date</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>$row[first_name] $row[last_name]</td>
                                    <td>$row[job]</td>
                                    <td>$row[phone_num]</td>
                                    <td>$row[home_address]</td>
                                    <td>$row[postcode]</td>
                                    <td>$row[home_phone_num]</td>
                                    <td>$row[date]</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>';
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "no information";
}

echo $modal;
$connection->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work.